# pointer to int after pthread_join() causes crash

Tags: c, pthreads

While tinkering with pthreads, I ran into a confusing issue.

If I define a int pointer *after* pthread_join, it appears to crash the program. Any where before pthread_join, it works OK. I would like to know why is this happening.

**works.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *somefunction(void *vargp);


int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if (argc < 2){
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid usage, bleh\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int argu = atoi(argv[1]);
    pthread_t tid;
    int rc = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, somefunction, &argu);
    assert (rc == 0);
    void **retval;
    int foo = 10;
    int *foo_ptr = &foo;
    pthread_join(tid, retval);
    printf("retval is %d\n", **(int **)retval);

    printf("*foo_ptr is %d\n", *foo_ptr );


    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


void *somefunction(void *vargp){
    int *someint = (int *) vargp ;
    *someint = *someint * 3;
    printf("In somefunction, someint value is %d\n", *someint);
    pthread_exit(someint);
}
```

**fails.c**

if the int *foo_ptr is after the pthread_join(), it causes me crash:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *somefunction(void *vargp);


int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if (argc < 2){
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid usage, bleh\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int argu = atoi(argv[1]);
    pthread_t tid;
    int rc = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, somefunction, &argu);
    assert (rc == 0);
    void **retval;
    pthread_join(tid, retval);
    int foo = 10;
    int *foo_ptr = &foo; // <-------- this line causes a crash 
    printf("retval is %d\n", **(int **)retval);

    printf("*foo_ptr is %d\n", *foo_ptr );


    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


void *somefunction(void *vargp){
    int *someint = (int *) vargp ;
    *someint = *someint * 3;
    printf("In somefunction, someint value is %d\n", *someint);
    pthread_exit(someint);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Red herring on the cause. Compilation on OS X blew up at 'retval'.

You've got a "void **" there, but what you want to do is pass in the value that's going to be filled in with the exit value. You need to create some storage for that, but all you're doing is passing in an uninitialised pointer.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int argu = 21;
    pthread_t tid;
    int rc = pthread_create(&tid, NULL, somefunction, &argu);
    assert (rc == 0);
    void *retval = NULL;
    pthread_join(tid, &retval);
    int foo = 10;
    int *foo_ptr = &foo;
    printf("retval is %d\n", *(int *)retval);

    printf("*foo_ptr is %d\n", *foo_ptr );

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

EDIT: Your code is a little obtuse but you don't actually have a problem with 'someint' going away in 'somefunction' when the thread closes and its stack is discarded, because 'someint' is actually just the value passed in, and the value passed in was a *pointer to* an integer on the stack in `main`.

Comment: it works when void **  replaced with your suggestion. Question: won't just `void *retval;` suffice instead of`void *retval = NULL;` ..?

Comment: @struggling_learner — yes, it is not crucial that `retval` is initialized to null as long as you don’t use it if `pthread_join()` fails.  It is safer to initialize it.

Comment: Yeah it's just a habit from many years with C; especially with `void *`. It doesn't apply in this particular use case here, but in general it can save your bacon sometimes. Crashes due to an accidental null pointer dereference are far more predictable and easier to debug than crashes due to dereferencing a pseudorandom, uninitialised value (that said, many modern compilers zero-initialise memory in debug builds automatically to assist with this).

Answer (score 2):

You're expected to use [`pthread_join()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) more like this:

```
void *rv;
int err;

if ((err = pthread_join(tid, &rv)) != 0)
    …report join failure using err…
else
    …rv points to what the thread returned…
```

This passes a `void **` to `pthread_join()`, but it is different from what you did — it passes a pointer to a `void *` variable, not an uninitialized value.

Note, too, that the returned pointer must (should) be a pointer to something that survives after the thread function exits — a global variable, or a dynamically allocated memory, or possibly a pointer to
memory made available to the function via the argument passed to the thread function when it was started, or something similar.  Returning a pointer to an `int` variable from the thread function's stack is wholly and utterly unreliable.  When studied closely enough, your code does use the pointer that was passed as an argument to the function, so that much is safe.